# Eclipse Papyrus UML plugin fails to load list of C++ stereotypes in class diagram

Tags: c++, eclipse, uml, papyrus

I am still new to Papyrus, but have been following along with some tutorials.

I am working on a C++ class model and was trying to add some stereotypes to some class properties. But when I go to the class Profile, Apply Stereotypes option, or even the class property Apply Stereotype option, the list of available stereotypes is always empty. I added the AnsiClibrary and the STD packages already, so those data types and such are there. But for some reason my list of available stereotypes is always empty.

I there something I am missing in getting the stereotype list to populate?

I included a picture. 
[image]

Comment: how did you add the STD package?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, from your image, that you do not have the C_Cpp profile applied.

Did you instal the Designer-CPP (Incubation) additional component? That's the component that provides the CPP stereotypes.

Once you have that component installed, you will be able to add the "C/C++ profile" (a.k.a, "C_Cpp") to your model (by using the [+] button in the Profile tab of the Properties view for the model) and then apply the stereotypes it provides to your model elements. At that point, the stereotypes should be visible. If not, you can use the "Appearance" tab of the properties view for the element to make the stereotype visible.

Comment: Oh okay. I will give that a shot. I probably saw that component, but perhaps did not install it because of the "Incubation" tag. I will respond back once I try that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as of December 2019 and found a solution. For those who are having the same problem, might find a solution like this:

1. Copy latest Papyrus link, by visiting [here](https://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/download.html).
2. Open Eclipse. `Help->Install New Software`, paste your link here and install Papyrus.
3. Copy [this link](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/components/designer/) directly.
4. Go to `Help->Install New Software`, paste your link here.
5. Make sure you check `Papyrus C++ profile, ...` as in the image. (I am not sure if the other checks are required.)
6. At the end of the installation you should have both Papyrus and its C++ available for code generation out of UML.

[image: PapyrusCppProfile]

References:

1. https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_Code_Generation